# Geting tasklist in xls or CSV format

Tags: java, cmd, createprocess, tasklist

I want to make a program in java that stores the tasklist in an excel file in the same folder where the program is stored.
I used the command:-

```
Process p;
  Runtime runtime;
  p = runTime.exec("tasklist.exe/ FO csv > tasklist.csv");
```

And also tried

```
p = runtime.exec("tasklist/ FO csv > tasklist.csv");
```

Both times receiving the error

> connot run program "tasklist /FO" : CreateProcess error=2, the system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Please tell me how to execute this particular function using java.

Comment: `CMD.exe` does redirection. Yet you are running a console program direct. `cmd /c etc`

Comment: try retrieving the tasks u shall get from  `runTime.exec("tasklist.exe/ FO csv` after than process these task to store in csv.

Comment: The switch character is not on the parameter. Change `tasklist.exe/ FO` to `tasklist /FO`.

Comment: After changing tasklist.exe/FO to tasklist /FO i am neither getting any output nor a file is being created

Comment: I repeat - CMD.exe does redirection. Yet you are running a console program direct. `cmd /c etc`